# Use C# class in XSD element

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have XSD file and I want to add an enumeration to this. So far it's easy, but how do I do it when the enumeration already exists in a C# file? The file is in the same namespace.

Here is what I tried to do:

**XSD**

```
<xs:element name="Type" ref="MyType">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
      My type
    </xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

**C# class**

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://...MyFile.xsd")]
public enum MyType {A, B, C}
```